# AnyLogic: Agent not sure where exactly it need to go

Tags: java, simulation, anylogic

The **delay1** can only contain `agent.paint`. On the exit of the **delay1**, a new agent gets released from the **delay**.
But the released agent is not an `agent.paint` instead it is an `agent.repair` or `agent.bwork`.
The **delay2, delay4, and delay7** can contain `agent.repair` and `agent.bwork` but these delays are full, so now the agent is a problem, which is not supposed to happen.

**Problem:**

In **delay1** only `agent.paint` can go, after getting free from **delay** and In **delay2, delay4 or delay7** only `agent.repair` or `agent.bwork` can go,  if **delay** have them.
And that is not happening in the existing model.

I try to explain in the image below:
[image]

My existing approach which is no working.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several things that are incorrect in your model. First of all, please keep in mind that when you use the word **agent** in a flowchart block, it always refers to the agent contained in the **current flowchart block** from where you are calling it.

I assume, in the "on exit" function of `delay1` you want to release an agent from `delay` which has a parameter `paint == true`. However, you wrote the function as

```
if (delay.size() > 0 && agent.paint == true) delay.stopDelay(delay.get(0));
```

The second condition `agent.paint == true` refers to the current agent in `delay1` flowchart block and not the agent in the `delay` that you want to release. Additionally, you are calling `stopDelay()` for the agent at position 0 in the delay block, regardless of whether this agent is the correct agent.

Instead, you need to iterate over all agents contained in the `delay` flowchart block, find the agent that meets your condition and release this specific agent. Your code can look like this:

```
if (delay.size() > 0) {
   Agent agentToRelease = null;
   for (int i = 0; i++; i < delay.size() {
        if (delay.get(i).paint == true) {   // Note: The function delay.get(i) is very slow. See if you can use Collection instead.
            agentToRelease = delay.get(i);
            break;
        }
   }

   if (agentToRelease != null) {
      delay.stopDelay(agentToRelease);
   }
}
```

The same goes for `delay2`, `delay4` and `delay7`.

The "on enter" function of `delay` is always called by the agent that is currently entering the delay. Because you check the condition for this specific agent here, you can directly call `stopDelay()` for this agent in case the condition returns true. So the first part of your code should look like this (the same goes for the remaining conditions)

```
if (agent.paint == true && delay1.size() + moveTo.size() < 2) {
   delay.stopDelay(agent);
} else if (...)
```

Comment: Do I also have to mention in the  'on enter' of the **delay** block which particular agent parameter should get released? if yes how? Right now its ' delay.stopDelay(delay.get(0)); '. kindly let me know, more detail about the **delay** 'on enter' given in the diagram above.

Comment: The "on enter" function of the delay block will be called by the agent that is currently entering the delay block. So if the parameter is correct (= if condition returns true) then you can just use `delay.stopDelay(agent)` instead of calling `delay.stopDelay(delay.get(0))`

Comment: I edited my answer to include the code for the "on enter" function of the delay block

Answer (score 1):

in delay you are using stopDelay with an agent without caring for the value of its 3 parameters.
So it's perfectly possible to release an agent that is NOT paint when delay1 is empty... and this agent will go to any of the other 3 delays... no reason why not to.

Besides this.. you have moveTo blocks that mess up your condition... so if an agent is in moveTo4 and delay2 is empty, it will go to delay 2 anyways... because why not? You don't have any restriction for that to happen

You are overcomplicating an extremely simple problem

Comment: How i can use StopDelay to leave an agent which has a  particular parameter? 
for example, I tried delay.stopDelay(agent.paint) but that is wrong.

Comment: Please always open new issues for new questions, see https://www.benjamin-schumann.com/blog/2021/4/1/how-to-win-at-anylogic-on-stackoverflow :)